# BSODs display: Driver Power State Failure W8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, bsod

That's the name of the countless BSODs my laptop's been showing me.
Even after following the instructions on some of the questions asked on this site I can't understand or even read any more of the dmps with WinDBG.

Please, will *you* help me fix my young 900€ PC?
Thank you a lot.

Here's the ZIP file: [At mediafile](http://www.mediafire.com/download/23gd1k0gxpb1oa7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a Driver Power State Failure becasue of ACPI issues with the `Intel(R) Xeon(R) processor E3 - 1200 v3/4th Gen Core processor PCI Express x16 Controller` (`PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0C01`).

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe0010bf03880, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd0011c05b960, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0010bf30a90, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.3.9600.18090 (winblue_ltsb.151014-0600)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  N551JX

SYSTEM_SKU:  ASUS-NotebookSKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0       

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  N551JX.202

BIOS_DATE:  01/16/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  N551JX

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0       

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffe0010bf03880

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd0011c05b960

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe0010bf30a90

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53d0f1d4

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80011b4b000 pci

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a22

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1C'00000000 (cache) 1C'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DELL-LAPTOP

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  09-11-2016 09:42:47.0092

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd001`1c05b928 fffff803`4c28f536 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe001`0bf03880 ffffd001`1c05b960 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd001`1c05b930 fffff803`4c28f456 : ffffe001`0bf30338 ffffe001`0f0a1880 ffffe001`0bf30300 fffff803`4c115759 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
ffffd001`1c05b990 fffff803`4c116bd8 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd001`1c05bae0 00000000`00000001 ffffd001`213eb180 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
ffffd001`1c05b9e0 fffff803`4c1dd3ea : ffffd001`213eb180 ffffd001`213eb180 ffffd001`213f73c0 ffffe001`0a1737c0 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x4f8
ffffd001`1c05bc60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd001`1c05c000 ffffd001`1c056000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  81a7ba75a791115b4f55c8910c64a260d525502e

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  b4ad1c5ace16e5a03331b4856dbd5b1986faa70f

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  f08ac56120cad14894587db086f77ce277bfae84

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.17238

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

TARGET_TIME:  2016-09-09T17:26:06.000Z

OSBUILD:  9600

OSSERVICEPACK:  18090

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 8.1

OSEDITION:  Windows 8.1 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2015-10-14 15:50:28

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  151014-0600

BUILDLAB_STR:  winblue_ltsb

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.3.9600.18090

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 263f6

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_acpi_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {20ddeb92-07eb-ebdc-bd08-44da71ffbd68}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

4: kd> !irp ffffe0010bf30a90
Irp is active with 6 stacks 4 is current (= 0xffffe0010bf30c38)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe0010a5fdad0 00000000 fffff80011b50b30-ffffe0010a5f6a10 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\ACPI pci!PciBusPowerUpCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe0010a5f68c0 00000000 fffff8034c1a8c0c-ffffe0010bf30338 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\pci  nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe0010bf30338    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
4: kd> !podev ffffe0010bf03880
Device object is for:
  DriverObject 0bf64060
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000022 AttachedDev ffffe0010a5fdad0 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe0010bf03f98:
PowerFlags: 00000040 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=4
Dope: 00000000:
4: kd> !devstack ffffe0010a5fdad0
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe0010a5f68c0  \Driver\pci        ffffe0010a5f6a10  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe0010a5f6890

> ffffe0010a5fdad0  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe0010a5d1910  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe0010a5fdaa0

  ffffe0010bf03880  \Driver\pci        ffffe0010bf039d0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe0010a5fa010 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0C01&SUBSYS_177D1043&REV_06\3&11583659&1&08"
  ServiceName is "pci"
```

Play with the P[CIe Link State Power Management settings in control panel](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/292971-pcie-link-state-power-management-turn-off-windows.html). Also update the [nvidia GPU driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/107010/en-us), your is nearly 1 year old:

```
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Tue Nov 24 19:07:35 2015
```

Maybe this GPU driver causes the PCIe issue.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my late reply. So, I already had the former turned off, and I actually reverted to an older driver *after* the same blue screen appeared. I hope both drivers (the old one and the new one) were the cause. I'll let you know when/if more BSODs appear. Hopefully not.

Comment: I encountered another Driver Power State Failure. Alas, I'm back to square one.

Comment: update the GPU driver to the lastest one

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I did, unfortunately. Do you want me to send you the new dmp? It seems to be rather similar to the old one, though.

Comment: nVIDIA released a new driver today: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/107562/en-us try this one

Comment: I will try to do a clean install of it, then.

Comment: Another one. Sigh.